How to fix unable to load routerlogin.net on Netgear C6300 modem router
Netgear C6300 when on firmware version V2.01.26 , most browsers will fail to load the router login page, its because of this issue mentioned here
The proposed solution it the thread was to use IE, but its not easy to install IE in 2024, Is there an alternate solution?

The trick is to use Seamonkey browser which is available on most OS, I was able to verify that I can successfully load the C6300 router login without issues as of 2024/04.
Tested on:

Seamonkey (2.53.18.2) --> Works!
Firefox --> does not work
Safari --> does not work
Chrome --> does not work
Opera --> does not work
Microsoft Edge --> does not work
Microsoft IE --> unable to install

